# Work with Google Recapcha on Android

Tags: java, android, recaptcha

I have an app which used a Russian insurance service to check for insurance policies. It worked in this way:

1. Download custom captcha
2. Show it to the user
3. Send request with answer to the service.

Yesterday, the service changed from custom captcha to Google ReCaptcha V2 http://dkbm-web.autoins.ru/dkbm-web-1.0/osagovehicle.htm

So, my question is: is it possible to show this captcha to the user and then send answer to this server in an Android app? I do not have access to the backend of this service.

I know that there are some services to recognize google recapcha, but all of them are paid. So, I am looking for a free service for this captcha (user must recognize a captcha in the app)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. There is a SafetyNet reCaptcha implementation already integrated with the Android OS libraries. See this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/recaptcha.html).

Comment: Are you sure? I do not have an access to the backend of the site. 100% that i will get thiserror: RECAPTCHA_INVALID_PACKAGE_NAME